# Python - How to Save 2 values outputf.write

Tags: python

I am trying to save user:password if  got 200 response status code to a textfile.

but it only saves one value "User" I dunno why. I've tried to add multi values with failed attempts.

```
outputFilepath = "validaccounts.txt"

def OutPut(text):
    with open(outputFilepath, "a") as outputf:
        outputf.write("{}\n".format(text))
        #headers removed#
        #Payload removed#
        response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
    #print(response.text)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            OutPut(user, password)
    except:
        pass
```

How to make it save User:password format in textfile what needed to be edited in outputf.write?

Note: I've removed the payload + headers, I just need to fix the output save user:password part.

Thank you,
regards.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by doing the following:

```
def OutPut(text, text1):
    with open(outputFilepath, "a") as outputf:
        outputf.write("{}:{}\n".format(text, text1))

output(user, password)
```